# Permission to access "All Contacts" tab in SFMC Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloud, builder, sfmcadmin

What is the right menu for setting up access to the "All Contacts" menu in the Contact Builder?
I have set options in Contacts (image below) but this menu isn't accessible yet.

[image]

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you should be able to see the "All Contacts" tab due to the tick near "View All Contacts" permission and it seems that no other roles are applied. Have you tried opening a SF Support case?
P.S. you might need to drop the cache and relogin to see the changes.

Comment: Hello Nicko! Tks for your response. Yes, I'll have a meet today to check this point! btw many thanks for your help, it seems like the right permission is already set.